# ASP.NET report - setting parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services, ado.net

I have a stored procedure named "Graph" that should get a value to the parameter @Material, and I created a report in ASP.NET that should show a chart using the data from the stored procedure.

However, when I try to load the report I get:

> "Data is unavailable"

Meaning, the parameter is not set correctly (with default value it works...)

The code-behind:

```
public partial class StatisticsPage : Page
{
    string Connectionstring = "server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=PhilipsMaterials;Integrated Security=SSPI";

    protected void btndisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindReport();
    }

    private void BindReport()
    {
        SSRSReport report = new SSRSReport();
        SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] {
         new SqlParameter("@Material","453567068441") };
        string ReportDataSource = "DataSet1";
        bool bind = report.CreateReport(Connectionstring, "graph", sqlParams, ref ReportViewer1, ReportDataSource);

        if (bind)
        {
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}

public class SSRSReport
{     
    public bool CreateReport(String Connectionstring, string StoreProcedureName , SqlParameter[] parameters, ref Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer ReportViewer, string ReportDataSource)
    {
        bool reportbind = false;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
        {

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = StoreProcedureName;
            com.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            da.Fill(ds);
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource(ReportDataSource, ds.Tables[0]);
            if ( ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
                ReportParameter myParam = new ReportParameter("Material", "453567068441");
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(myParam);
                ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
                reportbind = true;
            }                       
        }
       return reportbind;
    }
}
```

The markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StatisticsPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="StatisticsPage" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Test SSRS</title>
</head>
<body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="610px" Width="1179px" ShowParameterPrompts="true">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc" >
                <DataSources>
                    <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
                </DataSources>
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="PhilipsMaterialsDataSetTableAdapters.GraphTableAdapter" >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Material"/>
          </SelectParameters>
          </asp:ObjectDataSource>
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
          </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but why are you using both `LocalReport` and `ServerReport`?  Don't you have to pick one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

If the error occurs without a default parameter, then the issue is that an `<asp:parameter>` does not supply a value unless you provide one.  You can set the DefaultValue property from markup or code, which this value is passed directly to the backend.  You can also switch to the ControlParameter, SessionParameter, etc. which pulls the value from somewhere else.

Comment: I believe it's `ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["Material"].DefaultValue = "X";`

Comment: Thanks, the code does not recognize ObjectDataSource1 in the way you wrote. Can you give an improved code line?

Comment: Your code sample has ObjectDataSource1, so I was going off of that.  Replace ObjectDataSource1 with your control's ID>  Also, you could alternatively catch the Selecting event on the ObjectDataSource and assign the values that way too.